# Prism have register type within scopes or multiple containers

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism

We are using wpf and prism in our application. Our App-class inherits from PrismApplication which have a DI-container,a property named Container.

We want to be able to register types in scopes or have multiple containers. The effective goal would be to have types registered within a specific scope.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520399/prism-unity-container-per-module), seem to have a similiar goal (not same, since they want to cut it per module), but I dont see where you can set this NewContainer in the App (see link, answer 1). The Container-property is readonly.

Ill tried to keep this post/question short. Please tell me if its not clear.

Comment: The base class provided one container. If you want several, then you'll have to create these yourself.

Comment: Ok, How to I resolve or (constructor)inject objects from those containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prism >=7, you can replace the default container in your application base class that derives from `PrismApplication` by overriding the `CreateContainerExtension` method.

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
    {
        return new MyContainerExtension();
    }

    // ...your application code
}
```

Your custom container implementation should derive from `IContainerExtension<TContainer>`. You can find a more detailed description about this in the [Prism Documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dependency-injection/add-custom-container.html). Although it is intended for Xamarin, it works the same way in WPF.

As stated in your linked answer, there is no built-in way of passing different containers to modules or scoping them, but the solution provided there is exactly the way that you can achieve this. However, if you register the container in the way described above, you can continue using the `IContainerExtension`, `IContainerRegistry` and `IContainerProvider` interfaces without the need to expose the underlying container with e.g. `IUnityContainer` to your modules. You will only need it for creating child containers with `CreateChildContainer`. To be able to access it, you can always get the underlying container with the extension method `GetContainer` on `IContainerExtension` and `IContainerProvider`.

If you do not want to create child containers for modules but for scopes, you can modify the example by instantiating the child containers in your application class and assigning names to them in a dictionary. Then you could create a provider `IScopedContainerProvider` with a method `GetContainer(string scope)` that you inject where you need it. If there are few specialized scopes, you can also create separate container interfaces, like `IDatabaseContainer` or `IBusinessContainer` that directly access the corresponding scoped container.