# Prism - use child IoC container per shell in multiple shell application (WPF)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, prism, unity-container

I'm working on multiple-shells application. We use prism (with unity container). Application can have multiple shells, same approach uses Microsoft Word for instance.

The question is - what is the right way to create and use child container per shell?

Here are two approaches I found:

---

There is old article that shows how child container can be used per shell [check here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640573/ViewModel-1st-Child-Container-PRISM-Navigation) . The main idea is to create own implementation of IRegionNavigationService and add extra argument into RequestNavigate methods, for instance:

```
public void RequestNavigate(Uri target, Action<NavigationResult> navigationCallback, IUnityContainer containerToUse)
    {
        if (navigationCallback == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("navigationCallback");
        if (containerToUse == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("containerToUse");

        try
        {
            this.DoNavigate(target, navigationCallback, containerToUse);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.NotifyNavigationFailed(new NavigationContext(this, target), navigationCallback, e);
        }
    }
```

Then using series of extension methods we can control how to execute RequestToNavigate so that child container will be used when items are injected via constructor or property injection is being used. Here is an example of calling navigation:

```
  regionManager.RequestNavigateUsingSpecificContainer("MainRegion", uri, HandleNavigationCallback, childcontainer);
```

This is probably good approach, but it requires to change Prism main services, and add new extension classes. Maybe there is another way of doing it? Does prism naturally support child containers?

---

The other approach is this maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520399/prism-unity-container-per-module), approach applied for container per module, it will probably work for shells too... but I'm not sure - I didn't try it.

---

All ideas and thoughts are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

P.S. I found RegisterScoped() methods in IContainerRegistry, but I was not able find any documentation about it.

Comment: The function name's not enough documentation for you? It's soooo obvious.... /sarcasm off ... the whole container-abstraction-bullshit should never ever have been made visible to the user of the library, and it should have been documented at least as well as each container. But the Prism team thinks that function names suffice, so live with it.

Comment: Maybe it's enough, but I just don't know the whole workflow, like you have to do A then B and then C, say if B is a RegisterScoped(), then question is - what are the A and C?